# does TLAB allocated object be shared after allocation?

Tags: memory-management, jvm, heap-memory

The design of TLAB in JVM Eden space kind of confuses me. My question is if the object is allocated by one thread in TLAB, then how could it afterward be shared with other threads? Will the TLAB area which is exclusive to one thread be re-assembled, or will the object get moved out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A TLAB is exclusively reserved for *allocations* made by one thread. It’s still memory within the same shared address space of all threads. In other words, it can be *accessed* by all threads.

Of course, an object can only be accessed by other threads, if you store a reference to it into a shared variable. Since in a correctly working JVM, other threads can only access the memory by traversing such a reference, it implies that other threads can only access memory of a TLAB that has been allocated for an object already by the owner and that at least the minimum initialization work guaranteed by the JMM has been done by the owner thread before the reference becomes observable.

This intrinsic correctness implies that other threads do not need to see the actual allocation status of the TLAB, so the maintenance information can be truly thread-local, e.g. held in CPU registers.

Regardless of whether an object is shared by multiple threads or not, it will only be moved away from its initial allocation, if it survived until the next garbage collection (if a copying collector is in use). But by the time this happens, the memory where the object has been allocated into is not a TLAB anymore, as what made this memory a TLAB was the way it was used.

After the memory region formerly used as a TLAB has been emptied by the garbage collector, it may also get reassigned as a new TLAB to a different thread (or used for a different purpose).

Comment: More precisely, objects are never moved out of TLAB. It's more like TLAB boundaries are moved. TLAB is not a separate area in the heap - it belongs to the young generation or G1 region or whatever part of the heap defined by the selected GC. TLAB is just a few per-thread pointers into the heap. When a thread allocates a new TLAB (i.e. sets up pointers to a new destination), the previous one automatically disappears becoming just the regular shared heap.

Comment: @apangin you mean, it stops being a TLAB before the object might get copied to a survivor space?

Comment: Yes. TLAB can be considered as a contiguous area of the [shared] heap preallocated by a particular thread. As soon as a thread preallocates a new TLAB, or GC happens (whichever occurs first), the previous preallocated area loses its connection to the thread.